# Updating timer inside render gives warning

Tags: reactjs, react-native, state

I know that it gives me a warning because it's not pure. But when I put it in `componentDidMount()` it doesn't update. It just reduces once.

This is what I have:

```
class timer extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      seconds: 900
    };

  }

  render() {
    setTimeout(() => {
      if(this.state.seconds > 0){
        this.setState({seconds: this.state.seconds-1})
      }
    }, 1000);
  }
}
```

How can I update the state somewhere else while still being able to use the `setTimeOut()` without a warning about that it isn't pure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you're trying to decrease one from number every seconds so you should handle that using setinterval method instead of settimeout. If you add it in componentdidmount function it will start decreasing imemdiately after initial rendering occured.

```
componentDidMount(){
    this.setInterval( () => { 
        if(this.state.seconds > 0){
        this.setState({seconds: this.state.seconds-1})
           })
        }, 1000);
}
```